# What is best practice of the the case of writing text output into S3 bucket?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow

My Pipeline(python) is writing text data which read from BigQuery.
I have two option for Writing text data into  S3  by my knowledge.

The first option is "Writer subclass" of custom Sink  writes each record ito S3 bucket directory.
It seems the transfer efficiency is very low in my experience.
The Writer spends about a second per 1 record.(Also My datasouce has millions records!!)

The second option is to send the the text data into GCS which was written into GCS in beforehand.
I seem this option is inefficient.
The reason is unnecessary traffic (upload/download) occurs between GCS and DataFlow.
(My Pipeline does not require to store the text data into GCS)

Is there better way to write into S3 than my two options?

Regards.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you provide more details about what your application is doing? For example, do you wish to store each record in a separate Amazon S3 object, or append data to an existing object? Can you instead store data in a 'local' file, then upload the file when it has a certain number of records? Have you considered sending data to [Amazon Kinesis Firehose](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/what-is-this-service.html) to capture streaming data and store it in Amazon S3?

Answer (score 1):

The first approach of writing a custom sink for S3 seems good. You could use a buffer to batch upload writes to S3 instead of writing a file per record. If your buffer is not huge then you can directly upload to s3 otherwise using the multipart upload API would be a good alternative as well. Code in [gcsio](https://github.com/apache/incubator-beam/blob/python-sdk/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/gcsio.py) might be useful here.

In the second case you can directly use the TextSink to write to GCS but you'll have to move the files from GCS to S3 somehow later if the data needs to live in s3 at the end.

I have also created https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-994 for tracking the need for supporting S3